# Add elements to an empty dictionary and then add to array

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have two string elements. I want to add them to a dictionary and then finally, add the dictionary to an array. I tried doing it like so..But it's not working...

I made a dictionary like so..

`var receiverDict = Dictionary<String, Any>()`

The 2 strings that I have are these..

`self.abc_Receiver1 = "test1"` &

`self.abc_Receiver2 = "test2"`

I tried to add it to the dictionary like so...

```
(self.receiverDict["name"]! as AnyObject).add(self.Smat_Receiver1) //HERE IT CRASHES
(self.receiverDict["id"]! as AnyObject).add(self.receiverId1)
```

But it crashes in the first line above.

Further, I had also made an array like so to add the above dictionary to this arraylike this...

`var arrayOfReceiverNames = [[String: Any]]()`

`arrayOfReceiverNames.append(self.receiverDict)`

But the crash is occuring while adding elements to the dictionary itself.

Comment: `self.receiverDict["name"] = self.Smat_Receiver1; self.receiverDict["id"] = self.receiverId1`?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using dictionaries in the first place. If you have a fixed set of keys (`id`, `name`), you should probably be using a `struct` or a `class`. That'll radically simplify your code (since there's no more `Any` and casting all over the place), and even potentialy speed it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, this is Swift. Your dictionary is clearly `[String:String]`

```
var receiverDict = Dictionary<String, String>()
```

Then use native Swift terminology without bridging to the Objective-C runtime and `add` is wrong anyway.

```
receiverDict["name"] = self.Smat_Receiver1
receiverDict["id"] = self.receiverId1
```

Or simpler in one line

```
let receiverDict = ["name" : self.Smat_Receiver1, "id" : self.receiverId1]
```

Declare the array also more specific

```
var arrayOfReceiverNames = [[String: String]]()
arrayOfReceiverNames.append(receiverDict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by doing:

```
var dict = [String:Any]()
var arrayOfDict = Array<[String:Any]>()

dict["name"] = someValue

arrayOfDict.append(dict)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the strings and the values, why not directly add them like below:

```
var arrayOfDict : [Dictionary<String,String>] = [["name1":"value1"], ["name2":"value2"]]
```

If you have them stored in a variable, just replace the string with your variable.

So in your case,

```
 self.abc_Receiver1 = "test1"
 self.abc_Receiver2 = "test2"
 var arrayOfReceiverNames : [Dictionary<String,String>] = [["id":self.receiverId1], ["name":self.Smat_Receiver1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've values set for both `Smat_Receiver1` and `abc_Receiver2` before creating the `Dictionary`, then you can simply use a one liner to create your `Dictionary`, i.e.

```
let receiverDict = ["name": self.Smat_Receiver1, "id": self.abc_Receiver2]
```

The type of `receiverDict` will be inferred automatically as `[String:String]`.

Now, create the `array` with `receiverDict` as,

```
var arrayOfReceiverNames = [[String:String]]()
arrayOfReceiverNames.append(receiverDict)
```